# ViewPager Refresh/Change Only Current Page/Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Am having viewpager with 3 fragments/page, I have to refersh only current page or fragment, am calling mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but its refreshing all pages,How to refresh or change only current page without refreshing or changing other pages

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @Piyush: I have to replace page(fragment) based on button click in page(Fragment), your answer is not usefull for me (without changing other pages)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this if you want to `Refresh/Notify` your page.

do this whenever you want to refresh page.

```
yourPager.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
yourPager.setCurrentItem(CurrentPosition); // this is suppose to be your pagePosition
```

this will `Notify/Refresh` your page.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Use addOnPageChangeListener listener

```
viewPagerSearch.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Step2: Use callback

```
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //check position with index page to refresh that page

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
```

Comment: Nope..This not helpfull for me

Comment: Try to with viewPagerSearch.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Answer (score 0):

> Try to set `offScreenPageLimit` to `View Pager`.

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

first of all you need to use a PagerAdapter which will be extending FragmentPagerAdapter in your MainActivity then in your getItem() method of the adapter use switch case for calling fragments like

```
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, instance 1");
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, instance 1");
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, instance 1");

            default:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance("");
        }
}
```

then set adapter in onCreate() of the activity like:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(new YourPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Then use the following methods in every fragment you have:

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    return f;
}
```

And

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            makeRequest();// do network calling and populate your views from here
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not connected\nto the internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

I have also faced the same problem but solved it using this solution. I hope this will help you too.